# Internal memory full of pictures, probably caused by Bitmap.compress(format, int, stream)

Tags: android, memory-leaks, memory-management, compression

My app is a Wifi chat app with which you can communicate between two Android units with text messages and snap camera pictures and send them. The pictures are stored to the SD-card.

I used to have an `OutOfMemoryError` thrown after a couple of sent images, but I solved that problem by sending the

```
options.inPurgeable = true;
```

and

```
options.inInputShareable = true;
```

to the BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray method. This makes the pixels "deallocatable" so new images can use the memory. Thus, the error no longer remains.

But, the internal memory is still full of images and the "Low on space: Phone storage space is getting low" warning appears. The app no longer crashes but there's no more memory on the phone after the app finishes. I have to manually clear the app's data in Settings > Applications > Manage Applications.

I tried recycling the bitmaps and even tried to explicitly empty the app's cache, but it doesn't seem to do what i expect.

This function receives the picture via a TCP socket, writes it to the SD-card and starts my custom Activity PictureView:

```
public void receivePicture(String fileName) {
    try {
        int fileSize = inStream.readInt();
        Log.d("","fileSize:"+fileSize);
        byte[] tempArray = new byte[200];
        byte[] pictureByteArray = new byte[fileSize];

        path = Prefs.getPath(this) + "/" + fileName;
        File pictureFile = new File(path);
        try {
          if( !pictureFile.exists() ) {
                pictureFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                pictureFile.createNewFile();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) { Log.d("", "Recievepic - Kunde inte skapa fil.", e); }

        int lastRead = 0, totalRead = 0;
        while(lastRead != -1) {
            if(totalRead >= fileSize - 200) {
                lastRead = inStream.read(tempArray, 0, fileSize - totalRead);
                System.arraycopy(tempArray, 0, pictureByteArray, totalRead, lastRead);
                totalRead += lastRead;
                break;
            }
            lastRead = inStream.read(tempArray);
            System.arraycopy(tempArray, 0, pictureByteArray, totalRead, lastRead);
            totalRead += lastRead;
        }

        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(pictureFile));
        bos.write(pictureByteArray, 0, totalRead);
        bos.flush();
        bos.close();

        bos = null;
        tempArray = null;
        pictureByteArray = null;

        setSentence("<"+fileName+">", READER);
        Log.d("","path:"+path);
        try {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, PictureView.class).putExtra("path", path));
        } catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
    catch(IOException e) { Log.d("","IOException:"+e); }
    catch(Exception e) { Log.d("","Exception:"+e); }
}
```

Here's `PictureView`. It creates a byte[ ] from the file on the SD-card, decodes the array to a Bitmap, compresses the Bitmap and writes it back to the SD-card. Lastly, in the `Progress.onDismiss`, the picture is set as the image of a full screen imageView:

```
public class PictureView extends Activity {

private String fileName;
private ProgressDialog progress;

public ImageView view;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    Log.d("","onCreate() PictureView");

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    view = new ImageView(this);
    setContentView(view);

    progress = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Laddar bild...");
    progress.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
            File file_ = getFileStreamPath(fileName);
            Log.d("","SETIMAGE");
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(file_.toString());
            view.setImageURI(uri);
        }
    });

    new Thread() { public void run() {
        String path = getIntent().getStringExtra("path");
        Log.d("","path:"+path);
        File pictureFile = new File(path);

        if(!pictureFile.exists())
            finish();

        fileName = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        Log.d("","fileName:"+fileName);

        byte[] pictureArray = new byte[(int)pictureFile.length()];

        try {
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream( new BufferedInputStream(
                    new FileInputStream(pictureFile)) );
            for(int i=0; i < pictureArray.length; i++)
                pictureArray[i] = dis.readByte();
        } catch(Exception e) { Log.d("",""+e); e.printStackTrace(); }

        /**
         * Passing these options to decodeByteArray makes the pixels deallocatable
         * if the memory runs out.
         */
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPurgeable = true;
        options.inInputShareable = true;

        Bitmap pictureBM =
                BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(pictureArray, 0, pictureArray.length, options);

        OutputStream out = null;
        try {
            out = openFileOutput(fileName, MODE_PRIVATE);

                    /**
                      * COMPRESS !!!!!
                    **/
            pictureBM.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);

            pictureBM = null;
            progress.dismiss(); }
        catch (IOException e) { Log.e("test", "Failed to write bitmap", e); }
        finally {
            if (out != null)
                try { out.close(); out = null; }
                catch (IOException e) { }
        } }
    }.start();
}

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            Log.d("","ONSTOP()");
            Drawable oldDrawable = view.getDrawable();
            if( oldDrawable != null) {
                    ((BitmapDrawable)oldDrawable).getBitmap().recycle();
                    oldDrawable = null;
                    Log.d("","recycle");
            }

            Editor editor = 
                    this.getSharedPreferences("clear_cache", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.clear();
            editor.commit();
    }
}
```

When the user presses the back key, the picture isn't supposed to be available anymore from within the app. Just stored on the SD-card.

In `onStop()` I recycle the old Bitmap and even try to empty the app's data. Still the "Low on space" warning appears. How can I be sure the images won't allocate the memory anymore when they're not needed?

EDIT: It appears the problem is the compress method. If everything after compress is commented, the problem remains. If I delete compress, the problem disappears. Compress seems to allocate memory that's never released, and it's 2-3 MB per image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I solved it. The problem was, I was passing an OutputStream to `compress`, which is a stream to a private file in the app's internal memory. That's what I set as the image later. This file is never allocated.

I didn't get that I had two files: one on the SD-card and one in the internal memory, both with the same name.

Now, I'm just setting the SD-card file as the ImageView's image. I never read the file into the internal memory as a byte[], thus never decoding the array to a bitmap, thus never compressing the bitmap into the internal memory.

This is the new PictureView:

```
public class PictureView extends Activity {

    public ImageView view;
    private String path;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        Log.d("","onCreate() PictureView");

        path = getIntent().getStringExtra("path");

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        view = new ImageView(this);
        setContentView(view);

        Uri uri = Uri.parse( new File(path).toString() );
        view.setImageURI(uri);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            Log.d("","Back key pressed");

            Drawable oldDrawable = view.getDrawable();
                if( oldDrawable != null) {
                    ((BitmapDrawable)oldDrawable).getBitmap().recycle();
                    oldDrawable = null;
                    Log.d("","recycle");
                }
                view = null;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Is it bad practice to put an external file as the image of an ImageView? Should I load it into internal memory first?

Comment: You sur that this fixed it? When you set the imageView to URI, you are stil loading it to memory "full size". Did you trying the sampling method?

Answer (score 0):

If you specifically want the image to be nullified from memory for sure when a user presses back you could override the back button and make your image clean up calls there. I do that in some of my apps and it seems to work. maybe something like this:

```
@Override

protected void onBackPressed() {
         super.onBackPressed();

         view.drawable = null;
         jumpBackToPreviousActivity();
       }
```

Im pretty sure there are some view methods that clear other caches and things like that. You can recycle the bitmap but that doesnt guarantee that it will be dumped right then but only at some point when the gc gets to it.....but Im sure you probably know that already :)

EDIT: You could also do the same thing in the onPause method. That one is guaranteed to get called. The other two may never get called according to the android docs.
 http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: Right, I know, but the GC doesn't dump it at all, not even after the app stops running. I don't see how onBackPressed() would make any difference. onStop() is called and executes the code without any effect. At least so it seems.

Comment: onStop() may not get called either and setting things to get called within the backpressed method would guarantee that the user actively causes the app to force the view to clean itself up. Sometimes relying on the onStop() and onDestroy() can be unreliable because onPause gets called first and then the other two will get called when that particular android build decides the device needs that memory back.

Comment: I had a similar problem with an app I made that allowed users to create drawings on a touch screen. I tried getting rid of the drawing in the onstop and ondestroy but I couldnt get the view and canvas to totally clean themselves up until I created a cleanup method that nulled all views and bitmaps and I called it in onbackpressed and also anywhere I could when a user left the drawing activity.

Comment: No, it doesn't make any difference. It appears the problem is the `compress` method. If everything after `compress` is commented, the problem remains. If I delete `compress`, the problem disappears. `Compress` seems to allocate memory that's never released.

Comment: I dont see in your code anywhere that your actually cleaning up the view itself. Try clearing that up in your onstop or onpause by not just cleaning up the drawable but the view itself.